# Is a holomorphic mapping from open unit disk to itself always biholomorphic (bijective)?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am learning to understand the behavior of holomorphic mappings from open unit disk to itself. And I found a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641657/a-holomorphic-function-is-conformal) said that a holomorphic function is always conformal, while another related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249992/conformal-mappings-from-the-unit-disc-to-itself) said that conformal mapping from unit disk to itself is always bijective.

Now after the reading I'm a bit confused about the relationship among holomorphic mappings, conformal mappings and bijective holomorphic mappings **from open unit disk to itself**... Are they all equivalent, or does there exist a holomorphic mapping from open unit disk to itself that is not bijective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(z)=\frac{z^2}2$, then $f$ is neither an injective nor a surjective map from the open unit disk into itself.

Comment: Thanks for the example. In that case can I conclude that not all holomorphic mappings from open unit disk to itself is conformal?

Comment: No. You seem to think that conformal maps are always bijective. That's not true. The map $z\mapsto\frac z2$ (from the open unit disk into itself) is conformal, but it's not bijective.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood... Does the 'no' mean that all holomorphic mappings from open unit disk to itself are conformal?

Comment: A conformal map is a holomorphic map $f$ such that $f'$ is never $0$. So, for instance, the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb D&\longrightarrow&\Bbb D\\z&\mapsto&z^2\end{array}$$is not conformal.

Comment: Got it, thanks.